# Summing the values of specific key in multidimensional array while keeping structure

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array that I am attempting to sum values on while keeping the structure of the array.

The array contains arrays of "financials" with data['tags'] of specific types of financial data. The keys of each "financial" is identical throughout the array, for example, every "financial" will have "revenue" and "expenses".

Company is also the identical throughout the array, but will need to be returned in the final array

Here is the exact format of the array of data I am working with:

```
$array = 
[
  [
    "financials" => [
      [
        "data" => [
          "tag" => "revenue",
        ],
        "value" => 1,
      ],
      [
        "data" => [
          "tag" => "expenses",
        ],
        "value" => 10,
      ],
    ],
    "company" => [
      "id" => 1,
      "name" => "company, inc",
    ],
  ],
  [
    "financials" => [
      [
        "data" => [
          "tag" => "revenue",
        ],
        "value" => 2,
      ],
      [
        "data" => [
          "tag" => "expenses",
        ],
        "value" => 20,
      ],
    ],
    "company" => [
      "id" => 1,
        "name" => "company, inc",
    ],
  ],
];
```

I am trying to figure out how to sum each "value" for each data['tag'] value, for example, if calculating the above array, the end result I am looking to get is:

```
[
  "financials" => [
    [
      "data" => [
        "tag" => "revenue",
      ],
      "value" => 3,
    ],
    [
      "data" => [
        "tag" => "expenses",
    ],
      "value" => 30,
    ],
  ],
  "company" => [
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => "company, inc",
  ],
],
```

Which keeps the original array structure but has summed financial values for each data['tag'] value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are all companies same?

Comment: yes, all companies are the same throughout since the above array is all financials by specific company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
$array = [
    [
        "financials" => [
            [
                "data" => [
                    "tag" => "revenue",
                ],
                "value" => 1,
            ],
            [
                "data" => [
                    "tag" => "expenses",
                ],
                "value" => 10,
            ],
        ],
        "company" => [
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "company, inc",
        ],
    ],
    [
        "company" => [
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "company, inc",
        ],
        "financials" => [
            [
                "data" => [
                    "tag" => "revenue",
                ],
                "value" => 2,
            ],
            [
                "data" => [
                    "tag" => "expenses",
                ],
                "value" => 20,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
$company = $array[0]['company'];

$summedArray = $usedTags = [];
$summedArray['company'] = $company;
$summedArray['financials'] = [];
foreach ($array as $set) {
    $data = $set['financials'];
    foreach ($data as $dataSet) {
        if (in_array($dataSet['data']['tag'], $usedTags) === false) {
            $summedArray['financials'][] = [
                "data" => [
                    "tag" => $dataSet['data']['tag']
                ],
                "value" => $dataSet['value']
            ];
            $usedTags[] = $dataSet['data']['tag'];
        } else {
            $summedArray['financials'][array_search($dataSet['data']['tag'], $usedTags)]['value'] += $dataSet['value'];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($summedArray);
```

I hope it would help you

Comment: I'll be so gratefull if you vote my answer up. thanks :)